# How do I put the contents of a text file on the server into an array in my Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I have a webpage with embedded Javascript code which defines the following array:

```
var words = [ "apple", "banana", "orange" ];
```

The array is then be fed into some output in the HTML part of the webpage. What I'd like to do is create a text file called "words.txt" with the contents that I can pull into the array, instead of hardcoding the contents of the array in the code.
The text file would look like this:

```
apple, banana, orange
```

How do I do this?

Comment: do you want read and write a .txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better keep file as js:

```
[words.js]
var words = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'];

[index.html]
<script src="words.js"></script>
<script>
    alert(words[0]);
</script>
```

---

If using some server side language like PHP, you can read file content directly to js variable:

```
[words.txt]
apple, banana, orange

[index.php]
$words = file_get_contents('words.txt');

$words = preg_replace("/(\w+)/g", '"$1"', $words); // add quotes around words.

?>
<script>
    var words = [<?= $words; ?>];

    alert(words[0]);
</script>
```

Comment: It would be better to use `json_encode()` instead of adding the quotes yourself.

Comment: @Barmar It would be, but OP wants file format as plain as `string, string, string` and not `{"string","string","string"}`.

Comment: `json_encode` will create `["string", "string", "string"]`, just like you are.

Comment: @Barmar But for non-programmers it's simpler to just write out words instead of making it structured. I have seen lot's of translations files with missing `"` or `,` breaking structure.

Comment: I don't think you understand. You use `explode()` to convert `$words` into an array. Then you use `var words = <?= json_encode($words) ?>;` to convert the PHP array into a JS array.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to read the file from the server. Here's how to do it using jQuery. If you want to use plain JS, you'll need to translate it to the equivalent code.

```
var words = [];
$.get("words.txt", function(data) {
    words = data.split(', ');
    // update webpage with words
});
```